# Weird Workflow Behavior in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, sharepoint-2007, lookup

I have a Document Library A and a list B.

When a document added to A, an item is created in B with the Title = A.Url. Another workflow runs whenever a document is updated in A which makes a lookup: B.Title = A.Url, and changes another column in B in found item.

Item Change Workflow always gives "Error Occurred: List item is not found". I modified the workflow to send me an e-mail containing the new (but unchanged) A.Url. It sent me the exact string with the one already in list B.

Anyways, why it can't find the item when the two columns are equal?

Thanks in advance.

### Edit:

I literally hate Microsoft Sharepoint.

Comment: Are you comparing the fields programmatically or through SharePointDesigner? you might want to use the A.ID and set that value in B instead (as well as setting a secondary value for the friendly display name) - this will let you compare the files even when the filename changes.

Comment: I'm using Sharepoint Designer 2007. Unfortunately, I'm not allowed to create any custom solution for this project. I can't use ID, because, probably other items with same IDs will be added to the target list B. I can't use GUID either because, it won't work because of same reason of this question.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to seem *very* unintuitive, but try "Building a Dynamic String" into a String variable, containing only [URL] from list A (or whatever the field name is). Then use this variable to perform your lookup against list B.

This voodoo magic has often worked for me when I encounter string comparison mysteries in SPD workflows.

Comment: I've found this voodoo magic is the ONLY option sometimes. For example, trying to find an ID (stored in a number column) using an Item's ID.